# AutoCompleteTextView can't copy/paste in a service

Tags: java, android, xml, android-service, autocompletetextview

I have an AutoCompleteTextView in a floating service. In java:

```
final AutoCompleteTextView editText = mFloatingView.findViewById(R.id.text_box);
editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
editText.requestFocus();
```

In xml:

```
        <AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/link"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textColor="@color/text"
            android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
            android:completionThreshold="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textWebEditText"
            android:background="@null">
        </AutoCompleteTextView>
```

[image]
The problem:

-the two handles do not appear

-the copy and paste buttons do not appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable the standard copy/paste for TextView, try this :

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

Also, if your app theme extends a .NoActionBar theme, you need to enable windowActionModeOverlay:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Are you overiding the onTouch event?

Comment: yes, but not for this element, and I checked to return true value on all ACTION_DOWN.

Comment: It's a known issue when you override ontouch event. So you have to handle the event yourself for the textview.

Comment: I don't have any ontouch event listener for the element editText. So, what can I do?

Comment: My app theme: Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

Comment: You can also remove textIsSelectable and add this instead : android:inputType="textMultiLine"